# How to sort an array of integers in descending order of the first digit?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

How can I sort a list of integers in Java in a way that would produce the following output?

Input : [7,8,32,97,27,2]

Output : [97,8,7,32,27,2]

The required ordering:

First the numbers should be sorted in descending order of their first digit, then in descending order of their second digit, and so on...

Comment: How'd you do? What did you answer?

Comment: I think you need to better specify the algorithm, but it looks like you want to reverse sort by character

Answer (score 11):

The ordering you require is a lexicographical descending order.

A lexicographical descending order is the order you'll get if you treat the numbers of the input list as Strings and sort them in descending order. If all the integers had the same number of digits, the lexicographical order would be the same as natural ordering of integers.

However, in case of integers with a different number of digits, the order is different.

For example, `[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]` would be sorted as `[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,10,1]` in lexicographical descending order.

Therefore my implementation :

1. Converts the `int` array to `String` array.
2. Uses [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[]%29) to sort the array into ascending order, according to the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) natural ordering (which for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29), compares two strings lexicographically) .
3. Converts back to the `int` array, reversing the order (to get descending order).

The implementation :

```
public static void lexSort (int[] array)
{
  String[] sarr = new String[array.length];
  // convent the array to a String array
  for (int i = 0; i < sarr.length; i++) {
    sarr[i] = Integer.toString (array[i]);
  }
  // sort the String array (descending lexicographical order)
  Arrays.sort (sarr);
  // assign the sorted String array back to the input int array in reverse order
  for (int i = 0; i < sarr.length; i++) {
    array[i] = Integer.parseInt (sarr[sarr.length-1-i]);
  }
}
```

Testing :

```
int[] input = {7,8,32,97,27,2};
System.out.println ("before: " + Arrays.toString (input));
lexSort(input);
System.out.println ("after: " + Arrays.toString (input));
```

Output :

```
before: [7, 8, 32, 97, 27, 2]
after: [97, 8, 7, 32, 27, 2]
```

A more elegant solution using Java 8 `Stream`s (note that this solution returns a new sorted array instead of modifying the original array):

```
public static int[] lexSort (int[] array)
{
  return IntStream.of (array)
                  .mapToObj (Integer::toString) // convert the integers to Strings
                  .sorted (Comparator.reverseOrder ()) // sort in reversed lexicographical 
                                                       // order
                  .mapToInt (Integer::parseInt) // convert the sorted Strings back to 
                                                // integers
                  .toArray (); // output the sorted stream to an array
}
```